# are there any complete html5 css3 polyfill?

Tags: html, css

I want to ask if are there any complete html5 and css3 polyfill script ( in one file )

because I developing websites with the latest web features so I am very worry about old browsers compatibility

I searched alot on google but I didn't find what I want.

Comment: This question is unclear to the point of being impossible to answer.  You'd need to describe what html5 features you want, what css3 features you want and what browsers you need to support.

Comment: I sayed that I want complete polyfill

Comment: I sayed that I want complete polyfill

Answer (score 1):

There is no polyfill for CSS3.

There might be a single JavaScript file that contains all of the HTML5 polyfills that can be written, but that tends to be bad practice.

It is best to use only the polyfills that your code uses.

If you are worried about real old browsers then it may make sense to only write in HTML4 and CSS2.1.

If you also want the newest then try Progressive Enhancement and, if you want to do extra work, write two versions of your website.

If you can limit your oldest browser to IE11 then you can use quite a few HTML5/CSS3 features.

Look on [caniuse.com](http://www.caniuse.com) for what is supported in your oldest browser.